# No attacking IP shown in logs

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

My security log shows brute force attempts against RDP but no offending IP number. Cyberarms Intrusion Detection detects nothing. Symantec Endpoint Security detects nothing (in traffic log).

How is this possible ?

How can I find this mysterious IP ?

Answer (score 3):

Enable Windows firewall logging. Microsoft Network Monitor would also work.

Comment: I am not using windows firewall but symantec endpoint protection

Comment: wireshark is detecting the IP but not symantec or Cyberarms. Strange.